React: Get sum of the child component values in the parent component
The parent component can access the values of the child component, but it is unable to sum the values of each child. The total shows 0 instead of the correct total.

I am expecting the correct total of values from each child compoent to show in the Total. Parent and child components as follows.
Parent component
import { useState } from "react"
import SingleEntry from "./SingleEntry"

const TaxSource = ({ type }) => {
    const [valuesFromSingleEntries, setValuesFromSingleEntries] = useState([])

    const sendDataToTaxSource = (value, index) => {
        const newValues = [...valuesFromSingleEntries]
        newValues[index] = value
        setValuesFromSingleEntries(newValues)
    }

    console.log(valuesFromSingleEntries)

    const total = valuesFromSingleEntries.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

    return (
        <>
            <h3>{type}</h3>
            <label
                htmlFor='income'
                className='block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 mt-6'
            >
                Income: {type}
            </label>
            {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => (
                <SingleEntry key={i} sendDataToTaxSource={sendDataToTaxSource} />
            ))}

            <p>Total: {total}</p>

        </>
    )
}

export default TaxSource

Child component
import { useState } from "react"

const SingleEntry = ({ sendDataToTaxSource, index }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
    const handleValueChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleBlur = (e) => {
        let inputValue = e.target.value
        if (!isNaN(inputValue)) {
            setValue(parseFloat(inputValue).toFixed(2))
        }
        sendDataToTaxSource(value, index)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className='sm:col-span-4'>
                <div className='flex mb-2 sm:w-128'>
                    <div className='flex flex-col mr-2 w-3/4'>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='description'
                            id='description'
                            placeholder='Enter description'
                            className='border-2 rounded-sm px-3 my-[-3px]  border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-transparent'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-col ml-2 w-1/4'>
                        <input
                            type='number'
                            step='0.01'
                            name='value'
                            id='value'
                            value={value}
                            onChange={handleValueChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            placeholder='Enter value'
                            className='border-2 rounded-sm pr-3 my-[-3px] border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-transparent text-right'
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default SingleEntry


Did you try to debug it? Is your handleBlur function called? Is sendDataToTaxSource called? Are they called with the right arguments? Are the state variables updating as expected?

@GuillaumeBrunerie Thanks for checking the issue. I did not debug. I'm new to react. Can you suggest a suitable function to replace handleBlur. I used handleBlur to update the singleEntry value when the focus is away from the input field.

I am not suggesting to replace handleBlur. I am simply suggesting to put breakpoints in the various functions you defined to check that they are being called properly and with the right arguments. Knowing how to debug code is extremely important in software development.

You didn't pass index to SingleEntry so it won't be able to update the right position in the array. The updated code should be:
{Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => (
  <SingleEntry key={i} sendDataToTaxSource={sendDataToTaxSource} index={i} />
))}

I have copied your code to test in codesandbox, after adding the index it works now:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/get-sum-kqxtcq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A65%2C22

I would guess the issue is because SingleEntry expects an index prop which you are not passing from the parent.
